# How can I find in an array of objects the main actor I need

Tags: c++, function, oop, constructor

This is my task:

I have done half of my code, but I'm struggling because I'm a beginner in OOP and I'm not sure how I can find movie where main_actor is Angelina Jolie.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        string name;
        int year;
        string prod;
        string actor;
        cout << "\nenter the film name " ;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "\nenter the production year ";
        cin >> year;
        cout << "\nenter the producer name ";
        cin >> prod;
        cout << "\nenter the actor name ";
        cin >> actor;
        obs[i].SetName(name);
        obs[i].SetYearP(year);
        obs[i].SetProducer(prod);
        obs[i].SetMaina(actor);

        if (actor == "Angelina Jolie")
        {
            cout << "The movie who has main actor Angelina Jolie is" << name << endl;
        } // Тhis is my attempt.
    }
}
```

Comment: So to find a film whose actor is Angelina Jolie, the first thing you need to do is write a second loop. First you get all the information, and only when you've got the information do you try to do something with it. So delete the `if (actor == "Angelina Jolie")` statement you already have and start with a new loop.

Comment: And to get the main actor and the name of a film you should use the getter functions you have written `GetName` and `GetMaina` That's what they are for.

Comment: Have you talked with your professor or a TA and explained that you're having trouble with some of these concepts? They are paid to teach you. That is literally their job.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a function that loops over your array and checks the main-actor:

```
bool findFilm(Film* films, int numFilms, string actor)
{
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i< numFilms; i++) {
        if(!actor.compare(0, films[i].GetyMaina().length(), films[i].GetyMaina()){
            cout<<"Film "<<films[i].GetName()<<" has main actor "<<actor<<"\n";
            found = true;
         }
     }
     return found;
}
```

Comment: I get error while compiling saying: expected a ';' .

Comment: @Hana The compiler should tell you where the semi-colon is missing.

Comment: @Hana Taking a wild guess I would say that you put the above function in the wrong place in your code. There is no missing semi colon in the code above if it is placed correctly.

Comment: Where exactly correctly, I've put it right after the first loop for.

Comment: @Hana Put it just above your `main`-function.

Comment: I tried it too, but now still I have two errors saying: expected a ')' and expected a statement. @melk

Comment: Now, I get 9 errors, and I haven't still learned about compare()  so I'm not allowed to use it. @melk

Comment: You don't need to use compare `actor == films[i].GetMaina()` will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please use getline() function for user input because `cin >> name` will save from name Angelina Jolie only Angelina. Because it is reading only whole words not including white space.

To use function getline() put this after `#include<cstring>`

```
#include <string>
```

So use getline like this :

```
cout << "\n enter the actor name ";
std::getline (std::cin,actor);
```

Another problem is that you need cin.ignore() between two inputs. Because you need to flush the newline character out of the buffer in between.

Before loop ask for data  like this :

```
cout << "how many films ";
cin >> n;
cin.ignore();
```

In  loop like this :

```
cout << "\n enter the film name ";
    getline(cin, name);

    cout << "\n enter the production year ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> year;

    cout << "\n enter the producer name ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, prod);

    cout << "\n enter the actor name ";
    getline(cin, actor);
```

b) (put this function in your class in public section right after string GetMania() ):

```
static void FindFilm(Film arr[], int cntFilms, string actor)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cntFilms; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].GetMaina() == "Angelina Jolie")
            cout << "The movie who has main actor Angelina Jolie is" << arr[i].GetName() << endl;
    }
}
```

And from main call it like this right after loop.

```
string actor = "Angelina Jolie";
Film::FindFilm(obs, n, actor);
```

Also it's better if you write escape sequence (or special character) for new line (\n) to the end of output message. Like this :

```
cout << "The name of movie: \n" << name;
```

Comment: I get an error saying: identifier "name " is undefined

Comment: I don't have an output where it says The movie who has main actor Angelina Jolie is , I'm not sure why.

Comment: And sorry my bad but I have to "(b) define the findFilm () function for the requirements of a)" as is written in my task, I don't know if you read.

Comment: Check my answer now

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is using C++ containers like std::vector, std::array instead of raw array. And of course, then you should fill them.

```
std::vector<Films> films;

std::array<Films, 100> films;
```

The seconds thing is, you should delete "Films() = default;" part. That declaration changes everything in C++.

After these changes, you will be able to use containers' template member functions and algorithm functions (like find(), find_if(), count() etc.)  to get what you need.

```
#include <algorithm>
```

If you are not able to do these changes, simply you can do it by looping:

```
 for(auto film : films){
       //comparisons, if checks, returns
    }
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use vectors

Comment: Write your own vector!